# Changing Javascript Arguments on the fly

Tags: javascript, node.js, unit-testing, mocha.js

I am writing unit tests for my Node.js application using Mocha. Since my tests include a lot of redundant `assert.equal(someFunction(arg1, arg2, arg3...), expected);`, I thought of doing something like this:

```
var assertEqual = function(func, result)
{
  assert.equal(func, result);
}

descrirbe('someFunction()', function() {
    var arg1 = ...
    var arg2 = ...
    var func = someFunction;
    assertEqual(func, result)

    arg1 = ...
    arg2 = ...
    assertEqual(func, result);
}
```

This obviously does not work as `func` will bind its argument when declared. Is there a way to pass those arguments by reference in Javascript instead, so that I can keep modifying them and just call `func` instead of passing the arguments every time?

Comment: What are you passing to func? At assert.equal it should be func() not func

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just make assertEqual return a function and have that function be what you call instead of func:

```
function assertEqual(func, expected) {
    return function() {
        var result = func.apply(this, arguments);//result if you called the old function normally
        assert.equal(result, expected);//pass/fail test
        return result; //return the result
    }
}

var func = assertEqual(oldfunc, result);
func(arg1, arg2);
func(arg3, arg4);

//example:
var func = assertEqual(function(a,b) {return a*5 - b}, 15);
func(4, 5); //=> 15, calls assert.equal(15, 15)
func(2, 8); //=> 5, calls assert.equal(5, 15)
```

**Update **
Same test as above using scope variables
    var arg1 = 4, arg2 = 5, result = 15; //some random scope variables
    function somefunc() {
        return arg1*5 - arg2};
    }

```
//same test and results as above
var func = assertEqual(somefunc, result);
func();
arg1 = 2;
arg2 = 8;
func();
```

Comment: How am I able to re-call this again with different arguments from func just by setting them under before `var func=`?

Comment: This will call the original function normally (e.g. if oldfunc = function(a,b){return a==b}) and func = assertEqual(oldfunc, false), calling func(4,5) calls assert.equal(true,false)

Comment: But I will need to reset oldfunc every single time with new arguments. That defeats the whole purpose as I might as well just call the function its arguments and pass it to `assert.equal`. I want to define a function, set which variables are its arguments, and when I change those variables, the arguments in the function change (so sort of pass by reference), instead of redefining the function with the new arguments. Does that make sense? Look at my code above. I call `assertEqual` again and reset the arguments without redefining what `func` is.

Comment: Think that should suit what you're looking for

Comment: Yep very close. Now I'm trying to make so that I can also change `expected` just by setting it. Since my tests are going to be very large, it would really help avoid re-setting the args and expected everytime in long calls as opposed to just setting those variables and calling `func()`.

Comment: Maybe I can pass expected as an argument and parse it out, as the last argument?

Comment: You'll be seeing a lot of ugly if you want to change expected. The two ways I can think of doing that is to make expected the result of a function or use assertEqual as necessary in scope

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me like you could just make the variables global, and instead of passing them to the function as arguments, you could set/reference them from anywhere in your code.

Edit:
In your example, the arguments actually are global, just treat them as such instead of as arguments.

Comment: They're not local. They're in a `describe()` function.